# Remove the middle element if the array length is odd, or the middle two elements if the length is even.

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to remove the middle elements from an array if it has an even length and also the middle element if the array's length is odd. The program runs when I compile it, however nothing changes in the results.I am also not sure if I am using the System.arraycopy method correctly(the first position is the original array, the second is where you want to start copying, the third is the destination array, the fourth is the starting position of the destination array, and the last position is the number of array elements to copy) Here is the code I have so far:

```
public void removeMiddle(int[] values)
{
  //lets say the array size is 10 
   boolean even = (values.length % 2 == 0); 
   int middle1 = values.length/2; 
   int middle2 = values.length/2 - 1; 


   if(even)
   {
       int[] copy = new int[values.length - 2]; 
       //copying the elements 0-3 to the new array
     System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, copy.length - middle1 -1);
     //copying the last 4 elements to the new array 
     System.arraycopy(values, middle1 + 1,copy, middle1, copy.length-middle2 - 1); 
    } 
    else if(!even)
    {
       int[] copy = new int[values.length - 1]; 
       //copying elements 0-3
       System.arraycopy(copy,0,copy, 0, copy.length - middle1 -1);
       System.arraycopy(copy,middle1 +1 ,copy, middle1 + 1, copy.length - middle1 -1 );

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexes are wrong while copying the second halves, array indexes start from 0.

```
public void removeMiddle(int[] values)
{
  //lets say the array size is 10 
   boolean even = (values.length % 2 == 0); 
   int middle1 = values.length/2; 
   int middle2 = values.length/2 - 1; 

   if(even)
   {
       int[] copy = new int[values.length - 2]; 
       //copying the elements 0-3 to the new array
       System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, copy.length - middle1 -1);
       //copying the last 4 elements to the new array 
       System.arraycopy(values, middle1, copy, middle2, copy.length-middle1 - 1); 
    } 
    else
    {
         int[] copy = new int[values.length - 1]; 
         //copying elements 0-3
         System.arraycopy(copy, 0, copy, 0, copy.length - middle1 -1);
         System.arraycopy(copy, middle1 ,copy, middle1 , copy.length - middle1 -1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although you create and correctly fill your `copy` arrays, you never use or return them:

```
public int[] removeMiddle(int[] values)
{
    //lets say the array size is 10 
    boolean even = (values.length % 2 == 0); 
    int middle1 = values.length/2; 
    int middle2 = values.length/2 - 1; 

    if (even)
    {
        int[] copy = new int[values.length - 2]; 
        //copying the elements 0-3 to the new array
        System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, copy.length - middle1 -1);
        //copying the last 4 elements to the new array 
        System.arraycopy(values, middle1 + 1,copy, middle1, copy.length-middle2 - 1);
        return copy; // <--
    } 
    else
    {
        int[] copy = new int[values.length - 1]; 
        //copying elements 0-3
        System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, copy.length - middle1 -1);
                      // ^
        System.arraycopy(values, middle1 + 1, copy, middle1 + 1, copy.length - middle1 -1 );
                      // ^
        return copy; // <--
    }
}
```

For odd lenghts, you also do not use the right array as the `arraycopy` source. Other than that, your `arraycopy` usage is completely fine.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, when I updated my code following these suggestions I still face the same problem. When I compile and run the program the results are the same as the initial array (not removing the  middle elements).

Comment: Did you assign the result to a new variable or replace the old array at the call site?

Comment: When called upon in the main method it is supposed to replaces the old array.

Comment: Can you post the code of the main method in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically, you can restate it as you want the first X values and last X values where X is the largest integer less than half the size.
Computationally, that means the rounded down result of `(size - 1) / 2`.

For example: 10 => 4, 9 => 4, 8 => 3.
Meaning that for an array of 10 elements, you want the first 4 and last 4 elements.

```
public int[] removeMiddle(int[] values) {
    int x = (values.length - 1) / 2;
    int[] copy = new int[x * 2];
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, x);
    System.arraycopy(values, values.length - x, copy, x, x);
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Dang, I was so proud of this very simple solution, and nobody like it. :-(

Comment: imo the better answer to the question, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the issue was. I needed to assign my testValue to a new variable in the main method. Here is the final answer that works. Again thanks for everyone's help:

Main method:

//Test removeMiddle()

```
            System.out.println("Before call to removeMiddle() "); 
            printArray(testValues1); 

            System.out.println("After call to removeMiddle() "); 
            testValues = myMethods.removeMiddle(testValues1);
            printArray(testValues); 
            System.out.println();
```

//Methods Class

public int[] removeMiddle(int[] values)
   {

```
   boolean even = (values.length % 2 == 0); 
   int middle1 = values.length/2; 
   int middle2 = values.length/2 - 1; 


    if (even)
{
    int[] copy = new int[values.length-2];
    //copying the elements 0-3 to the new array
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, copy.length/2);
    //copying the last 4 elements to the new array 
    System.arraycopy(values, middle1+1,copy, middle2, copy.length/2);

   return copy; 

} 
 else
{
   int[] copy = new int[values.length-1];
    //copying elements 0-3
   System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, copy.length/2-1);
   System.arraycopy(values, middle1 + 1, copy, middle1 + 1, copy.length/2-1);

   return copy;
```

}
}

Comment: Sorry the part in the else statement is incorrect. It should be: else
    {
       int[] copy = new int[values.length-1];
        //copying elements 0-3
       System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, copy.length/2);
       System.arraycopy(values, middle1 + 1, copy, middle1, copy.length/2);
        
       return copy; 
   }